# How to save data for specific user using Netlify Identity

Tags: javascript, html, netlify

I'm makinig HTML website and hosting it on netlify. For example I made like buttons next to paragraphs and i want to save those liked paragraphs for specific user with netlify identity. How can i accomplishe that

Comment: SO is a site to get help with your existing code, not to help you design something that you haven't yet designed.  
If you don't have current code, nor do you know how you'd design this on paper regardless of code implementation, then you need to do some [additional research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), make an attempt and, if you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried.

Comment: Code it self is useless. I have no idea what to do. I have no problem of designing it. Problem is that i don't know how to save data for user. I did some research but nothing. This is why i'm here asking for help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.